# UIMA ruta - why does it not work?

Tags: uima, ruta

For the text

```
level 110 KwH
```

I've got the rule

```
W{REGEXP("level")} NUM{-> MARK(energy_consumption)} W{REGEXP("KwH")}
```

but it doesn't work.

The text `level 110 KH` with the rule

```
 W{REGEXP("level")} NUM{-> MARK(energy_consumption)} W{REGEXP("KH")}
```

works. Why doesn't work the 1st rule?

Answer (score 0):

The rule does not match, because "KwH" is not one `W` annotation but two `W` annotations (actually `CW`). `KH` is only one W annotation (actually `CAP`). The `REGEXP` condition matches on the covered text of the matched annotation (which is "Kw"), thus the condition/regex is never fulfilled.

You maybe want to consider using a tokenizer additionally to the ruta seeder, or some dictionary lookup, or some rules combining the two CW annotations. The initial annotations provied by Ruta are just a starting point but no real tokens.

*DISCLAIMER: I ama developer of UIMA Ruta*